# What is the best lens to shoot the Milky-Way on a crop camera?

Tags: lens, canon, digital, astrophotography

I own a Canon 100d and i like to photograph the stars, I'd like to have a wide angle lens to capture the most of the milky way i can. Possibly as cheap as possible and have really good quality. 
Thank You Zoe.

Comment: I'd google "18-55" and "astrophotography". Your kit lens is probably your best option if you need cheap. See: http://nightskyinfocus.com/astrophotography/capturemilkyway/

Comment: You can also shoot with a longer focal length lens and then stitch together overlapping images of different parts of the sky. The image then has far greater resolution; to get such an image in one shot would require a much more expensive lower focal length lens mounted on an expensive full frame camera.